# Django Rest Framework reverse serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Please I need a little help. I have a model like below

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employee(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='employee')
    code = models.CharField()
```

In my EmployeeSerializer, how can I add the **Person** field
Something like:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    person = # Something the get **Person** instance
    code = serializers.IntegerField

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'id',
            'person',
            'code'
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`depth`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) option to get nested representation of related objects:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'id',
            'person',
            'code'
        ]
        depth = 1
```

If you need to customize nested object, you should use nested serializers as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).